# In the context of software analytics, is "analytic event" or "analytics event" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, terminology, technical

I'm a software engineer and we refer to "analytics" as the process of capturing data about the user's behavior. For example, we might send an event to Google Analytics to help us determine the percentage of users who are actually interacting with an important feature we recently added to an app.

When we add a new event like this, I'm never sure whether to refer to it as an "analytic event" or "analytics event". I've heard both from my peers. Is one of them incorrect?

Comment: There's not a way to work out which one is correct from basic principles. The singular form attributive is the norm (eg car park), but can be trumped by the plural form when there is a well established related usage of this as a simplex noun (thus systems ==> systems analyst) or to reflect a desirable plural usage. As this is a rare compound, you've really got to go with established practice. I'd model on physics lesson.

Comment: I don't know which is the most usual in common use, which is what you are asking for. The correct word for this is a *Sample*. It represents the data acquired for a certain number of people, even just one, at or during a certain time period. Making it an *event* smacks of marketing rather than analysis.

Comment: Well, "event" in this case refers to something occurring in the software. It usually signifies that the user took a particular action. For example, you might have an event called "SignupButtonPressed". The software reports this event to the analytics tracker, where the team can see things like how many times the button was clicked, how long it took the user to click the button, what percentage of users clicked, etc.


I took a look at Google Trends, and it does look like "analytics event" is searched for far more often than "analytic event".